# spring amqp switch off rabbit listener when not required

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have rabbit config xml which has listener definitions.

```
<rabbit:listener ref="someListener"
        queues="someQueue" />
```

If we comment the same , we can have the listeners not bound to the queue. But is there any other graceful way of doing it. Like control it based on Zookeeper property or something which doesn't require us to build and deploy the war again. We have an application which listens to the queue but to reduce the load , we are going to deploy the same app in another tomcat and we need to switch off the listeners alone there. If the load on current tomcat increases , we can disable the listeners here and enable the listeners in the new tomcat. Because our tomcat has other wars as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear: maybe you can share more config and what you would like to disable/enable and according to what condition.

If the story is about a static bean definition control on startup, you may consider to use a [Bean Definition Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles) feature from Spring Framework:

```xml
<beans profile="rabbitListener">
    <rabbit:listener ref="someListener"
        queues="someQueue" />
</beans>
```